# How to sync with my github repository?

Tags: github, windows-10

I have a GitHub repository.

I want to have it automatically sync the changes I made on my PC, to be in the GitHub.

I am on Windows 10.

I keep getting the error when trying to push.

It has this upstream message, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: show us the error

Comment: please add print screen or error message/

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/IOknD

Here is the screenshot.

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 0):

If the error is ['upstream' does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32912359/6309), double-check the values returned by `git remote -v` inside your local repo.

There should be a remote named origin. If not, add it with:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

Then, if you have made at least one commit, try a `git push -u origin master` (assuming your remote GitHub repo is a new one, still empty, meaning without `README` or any other file)

Comment: It isn't empty at all. This has many folders, files etc. That I uploaded from my local folder, etc.

But when I make changes to my local files, I want to sync them automatically with the github repository.